# Check usage before deleting an user(Model)

Tags: laravel, database, foreign-keys, relationship

I have a database, with more than 20 tables and each table has the created_by, modified_by, and deleted_by columns. I have to prevent users from deleting the entries from the Users table when it is used in any of the tables in any of the above columns.

Currently, I'm doing in a very long way:

```
public function operators()
{
    return ($this->hasMany(Operator::class, 'created_by', 'id')->count() +
        $this->hasMany(Operator::class, 'modified_by', 'id')->count() +
        $this->hasMany(Operator::class, 'deleted_by', 'id')->count());
}
public function sources()
{
    return ($this->hasMany(Source::class, 'created_by', 'id')->count() +
        $this->hasMany(Source::class, 'modified_by', 'id')->count() +
        $this->hasMany(Source::class, 'deleted_by', 'id')->count());
}

public function unit_types()
{
    return ($this->hasMany(UnitType::class, 'created_by', 'id')->count() +
        $this->hasMany(UnitType::class, 'modified_by', 'id')->count() +
        $this->hasMany(UnitType::class, 'deleted_by', 'id')->count());
}
public function in_use()
{
    return  $this->operators() + $this->sources() + $this->unit_types() + $this->users();

}
```

and checking the in_use() value greater than 0 and informing users, that the action is prevented. I hope there will be a simple way to do that, rather than repeating the same for more than 20 tables.

Comment: There is a simple and native way of doing this, you have to use foreign keys but you have to define them on the table if you did not already. So if you want to delete a user that exists in any of these tables, it will throw an exception (SQL error), else it will work and the user will be deleted without issues.

Comment: @matiaslauriti the tables were created without migration files long ago, and I'm not sure the FK is defined, need to manually go through them and define the relationship if it's not there. So, I'm looking for a way to inform the user via a notification,that this element cannot be deleted, without showing an exception or a 500 error

Comment: if I were you, I would try to add each foreign key (if possible, depending on the size of the tables) and that's it! when you want to run the `delete()`, use a `try-catch` and if it is a foreign key exception, then show the expected error to the user, do not throw it to them. Can you take that path?

Comment: @matiaslauriti that makes sense. I'll use that approach, thanks